# Запятая при приложении

Tags: запятая

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить запятые:

> Нашему земляку, поэту В.Кирееву было 4
> года, когда началась война.

*Земляк* и *поэт* - неоднородные приложения, значит запятая между ними не нужна. Может быть, выделить запятыми с обеих сторон *поэту Кирееву* как уточнение или оставить так? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта будут корректны. Можно выделить  "поэту В.Кирееву "(именно как пояснение или уточнение, но тогда дополнением будет "земляку", в нём главный смысл, а что он поэт -уточнение), а можно ничего не ставить: Нашему земляку  поэту В.Кирееву было 4 года, когда началась война. Вы сами всё объяснили: неоднородные приложения стоят перед дополнением. Если бы после него, запятые были бы нужны: Кирееву, нашему земляку и поэту, было 4 года...

Я бы ничего не ставила, и так всё понятно, без пояснения. Зачем подчёркивать, что он земляк? Или это важнее? Зависит от смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Приложения, действительно,  НЕОДНОРОДНЫЕ, поэтому запятую желательно убрать: "Нашему земляку поэту В.Кирееву было 4 года, когда началась война".

Похожий пример: Мой друг писатель Васильев жил тогда в Москве.

Уточнение можно применять в зависимости от контекста, и оно должно именно УТОЧНЯЮЩИМ, например: "Другому нашему земляку, поэту В.Кирееву, было 4 года, когда началась война".